# If OpenAM 10 is compatible with J2EE agent 3.5?

Tags: openam

If OpenAM 10 is compatible with J2EE agent 3.5?
I'd like to integrate tomcat 8 agent with OpenAM 10 instantion.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use J2EE agent 3.5 with OpenAM 10.